# TWS API and its connectivity

Tags: python, api, tws

I have installed a TWS API and I actively use IBKR trading workstation. I need to execute my python code for CPR indicators ;I am unable to figure out if my API is connected with the IBKR application. Is there a way to ensure if my API is connected or not before I execute my python code.

Tried installing the TWS API and used the python code to run. But seems like my API is not connected!

PS: I read through the initial set up for the Interactive Brokers user guide to activate the API but seems like something is missing ( CLient ID) for its connectivity. I do not know where to check the client id or the API connectivity.

Trying to code for CPR Indicators using Python and TWS API

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

In TWS click on the 'DATA' at the top right title bar of the window.
A window will appear, under 'API connections' you can check if your connection is listed.

If not post your code so we can help